# Sending keyboard input over UDP in network game

Tags: c++, network-programming, synchronization, udp

I am implementing networked asteroids over UDP. I was going to limit the user input messages the the client sends to just state *changes*. So only send a message when there is a key down or up on the arrow or space keys. This would greatly reduce the amount of packets sent from the client.

However, now that I have re-read Gaffers article on networked physics *and* his more complex one about making the UDP messages reliable I am rethinking. He states:

`The key to making this input stream tolerant of packet loss and out of order delivery is the inclusion of a floating point time in seconds value with every input rpc sent. The server keeps track of the current time on the server and ignores any input received with a time value less than the current time. This effectively drops any input that is received out of order. Lost packets are ignored.`

So it is not caring if a packet is lost. Now I am thinking that the vital packet that indicates keydown to thrust the ship forward could be the one to be lost, and never resent, thus breaking the game.

Am I therefore right in saying that the client is instead forced to send more regular (up to every physics update, 50 times per second) dumps of actual keyboard *state* rather than state *changes* to fit in with this scheme that is tolerant of packet loss? Or is there a more noble way?

Comment: This is one of the most difficult things in networked multiplayer games. There is no general solution which works for every game. Many action games use approximisation and predictions for these kind of things. I've programmed a multiplayer breakout/arkanoid/pong clone before and things were pretty hard to do fluently. Pixel action games require usually a pretty high accuracy in terms of positioning, but also timing.

Comment: The game will be played on my home network, CAT 5E, or on a University campus. My lag will be quite low. Currently < 3 ms in tests using C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a response to an identical question I asked over on gamedev: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26840/send-regular-keyboard-samples-or-keyboard-state-changes-over-network the concensus seems to be to only send keyboard state when it changes (at the time of key down or key up only). This generates hardly any traffic. It necesitates ensuring that these messages are reliable. This will be a challenge to achieve as the messge is time critical. i.e. even though the client can proceed to move their own player (ala client side prediction), the other clients need to be informed of the change in the state of their competitor, via the server, and in "real time".

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in my comment already, there is no answer to rule them all.

But in your case, I probably wouldn't transfer keystrokes but physics changes instead:

- Transfer only changes in physics, e.g. when the acceleration of objects (players, asteroids) changes and changes to the general game state (asteroid/player explodes, shots, score)
- When you do so, also transfer the current position of that object to compensate for lag (even with only 3ms, the positions of objects will differ by a little) and update positions of the appropriate objects (it might be sometimes looking like the objects will jump a bit, but almost every game has this issue).
- Everything else (world physics like gravity) can be computed on the client itself and don't need to be transferred over the network.

Comment: Even though I asked the question and you answered it, I'm inclined to strongly disagree. According to the eminent expert, <http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/networked-physics/>, transferring key state is what the client does and the *server* is the authority on the physics and presumably the collisions also.

Comment: Well, you're right - the server should be the **authority** for the whole game state - mainly to avoid cheating. But for displaying purposes, it doesn't hurt to predict/approximate movements on clients to lessen the bandwidth needed (you don't need 50 updates/sec of an object if you know the objects current velocity and acceleration vector).

Comment: I intend to do client side prediction with authoritative corrections from the server (timne permitting!), *but* my question was whether to transfer current keyboard state regularly or keyboard state *change events* only when changes occur. If the latter then an unlucky packet loss could break the game.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to handshake packets and repeat resends until handshake is achieved. You will need to do this in both directions of course. In the old days of serial this could be done with four control lines, two per end.